# CSS height "expanding" the wrong way

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make a thermometer that can keep display the percentage of donations received easily.

I got help on using jquery already to control the height of the div which will be the fill of the thermometer. However now that I am doing it vertically within the thermometer the "fill" moves in the wrong direction and I can't figure out how to reverse that since the height of a div "moves down"

Sorry I am having difficulty explaining this. Here is what I have so far:
http://bit.ly/jrHwHo

here is the css:

```
#thermometer { height: 377px; width: 180px; margin:5px; padding:0; border: #cccccc solid 1px; background: url(thermometer.jpg);}

#level { height: 250px; width:26px; margin: 0; padding:0;  background: #eb1c22;  position:relative; top:51px; left:71px; }
```

Here is the html:

```
<div id='thermometer'>
    <div id='level'>
    </div>
</div>

<br>
Type a number between 0 and 250: <br>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `position: absolute;` and `bottom: 0;` on the `div` you want to expand. Then, just make sure that the parent element (container of the expanding `div`) is set to `position: relative`.

```
#thermometer { height: 377px; 
               width: 180px; 
               margin:5px; 
               padding:0; 
               border: #cccccc solid 1px; 
               background: url(thermometer.jpg);
               position: relative;}
#level { height: 250px; 
         width:26px; 
         margin: 0; 
         padding:0;  
         background: #eb1c22;
         position: absolute; 
         bottom: 0px; 
         left:71px; }
```

If 0 doesn't work for you, just adjust it until it does. The point is to use `bottom`, not `top`.

Comment: Thank you! I was trying to use bottom but was not changing the position to absolute and relative. I'm still not sure I understand why that is necessary?

Comment: Absolutely positioned elements (which is what you're doing when you set `bottom`) are positioned absolutely *relative* to their closest parent with their position set to `relative`. Otherwise, the element might be absolutely positioned relative to the document body, or another (further away) parent element.

Answer (score 0):

Anchor it using `bottom` instead of `top`.

It looks like `bottom: -180px` will do it (and don't forget to remove the `top` property, or set it to `auto`).

#### Example using `bottom: -180px` and no `top`.

[image: Example]

Answer (score 0):

Use `bottom` instead of `top` to position the level element. That way the position will be relative to the bottom of the parent, and it will grow upwards.

Answer (score 0):

love the thermometer, just a suggestion, in your javascript add something to prevent a number larger than the goal to be entered or else the level of the "liquid" in the thermometer will go past the background.  What I would do is have a variable that is the max value.  Before setting the value of the height have it check the number entered against the max value.  If the number entered is more that the max value then make the height just go to the max.